# Excel VBA get listbox value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox value that has a string of text in it separated by commas. How can I get the value from this string after the 3rd comma?

Answer (score 0):

If the string is stored in YourString:
    Split(YourString, ",")(2)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work to get me the value. The only problem now is, how do I get the value without having to click the line of text in the listbox?  I tried 'afterupdate' but nothing seems to trigger getting the value unless I click the string of text.